# In SimpleExec, Command.Run(), how can I get return value into a variable

Tags: c#, build

We're using [SimpleExec](https://github.com/adamralph/simple-exec) for .NET C# command line builds.

Most commands we don't need to inspect the return value, but for some we do.

We run commands like:

`Run("git", "version");`

and in these scenarios, we want to assign the execution of these commands into a variable in our C# app.

Comment: Seems like the answer is right in the readme in the [Read](https://github.com/adamralph/simple-exec#read) section.

Comment: Thanks for this Jonathan - we'd used Run for so long in so many scenarios that we hadn't used the ReadAsync method.  Do you want to add this as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The readme in the [Read](https://github.com/adamralph/simple-exec#read) section shows the `ReadAsync` method for reading the stdout and stderr.